# Color Issue when texturing a surface

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]
[image: material texture issue]
Brand new blender user with no experience, trying to map a texture to a single side of a cube for an animation. I am having an issue where the black areas of the image end up looking white when applied to the object. The preview of the texture looks correct, but the material preview, as well as the actual render do not.

I have tried messing with all the settings, but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show some screenshots?

Comment: I have one picture up, I realize it might not be helpful. What do you need to see?

Comment: Oh, just didn't see, is your texture displayed properly in Texture view?

Comment: yes, the texture view is correct. You can see that it is supposed to be a person wearing a black shirt against a dark background, but all of this appears white in the 3d view

Comment: Can you show how it looks in render view

Comment: I added a picture of the render to the post.

Comment: Try to go to Node Editor and in between Diffuse and Material Output node plug Invert Node

Comment: I tried this, but I'm not sure if I am understanding correctly. [image](http://s1.postimg.org/7xshxq95r/Capture5.png)

Comment: could you upload your blendfile with the picture?

Comment: There was an image in my previous comment. Is that it or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Misread the comment, here is my blend file. [file](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/503618/intro_1.blend)

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is, but I deleted the material and created a new one and added the texture again and it seems to be working now. If anyone has any insight it is still appreciated, I am trying to learn.

Comment: Please use other hosting to share your file and make it easier for other to help you. Many of us dislike having to sign on to new sites or sharing private info just to download a file. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or pasteall.org